# Drawing a object with Box2D and HTML5 canvas on current mouse position

Tags: physics, javascript, box2d, html5, html-canvas

I'm attempting to create a air hockey type game with HTML5 canvas and JavaScript, using Box2dWeb for the physics calculation. I need a way to draw the puck at the current mouse x and y position every animation frame with Box2d. I've been researching for quite a while and haven't found a solution yet. I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you read [the manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html)?

Comment: Box2dWeb seems to have very poor documentation.

Comment: That's because *Box2DWeb* is automatic port of *Box2DFlash*, which is a manual port of the original C++ *Box2D*. Their APIs are essentially the same, so once you grasp [the basics](http://buildnewgames.com/box2dweb/) you can consult the C++ or Flash versions' documentation.